# OpenCart не сохраняет текст в расширении

Tags: php, opencart

Есть сайт на OpenCart, в админке создаю страницу с политикой конфиденциальности, вношу туда текст, но видимо, есть ограничение на кол-во символов. Причём, работает оно на кириллицу.
Пример: Политика конфиденциальности имеет примерно 15.500 символов в кириллице - не сохраняет.
Попробовал вписать текст рыбу на 16.000 символов в латинице - сохранилось.

Как решить данные проблему? Может быть, можно как-то увеличить размер данного текста? Где вообще можно найти эти ограничения? Впервые с OpenCart встретился.

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Попробуй глянуть в базе данных тип и сравнение этого поля

Comment: Еще бы понять, в какой таблице это поле находится)
В базе данных 5 страниц с таблицами. Я попробовал поиск по значению, но ничего не нашёл.